# Using SQLDF to select specific values from a column

Tags: sql, r

SQLDF newbie here.

I have a data frame which has about 15,000 rows and 1 column.
The data looks like:

```
cars
autocar
carsinfo
whatisthat
donnadrive
car
telephone
...
```

I wanted to use the package sqldf to loop through the column and
pick all values which contain "car" anywhere in their value. 
However, the following code generates an error.

```
> sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword="car")
Error: unexpected symbol in "sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword="car"
```

There is no unexpected symbol, so I'm not sure whats wrong.

so first, I want to know all the values which contain 'car'.
then I want to know only those values which contain just 'car' by itself.

Can anyone help.

**EDIT:**

allright, there was an unexpected symbol, but it only gives me just car and not every
row which contains 'car'.

```
> sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword='car'")
  Keyword
1     car
```

Comment: You have at least one set of closing parentheses missing in your statement...

Comment: you need to escape the quotes sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword=\"car\"").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `=` will only return exact matches.

You should probably use the `like` operator combined with the wildcards `%` or `_`.  The `%` wildcard will match multiple characters, while `_` matches a single character.

Something like the following will find all instances of `car`, e.g. "cars", "motorcar", etc:

```
sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword like '%car%'")
```

And the following will match "car" or "cars":

```
sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword like 'car_'")
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `sqldf`; your SQL statement is the problem.  You need:

```
dat <- data.frame(Keyword=c("cars","autocar","carsinfo",
  "whatisthat","donnadrive","car","telephone"))
sqldf("SELECT Keyword FROM dat WHERE Keyword like '%car%'")
#    Keyword
# 1     cars
# 2  autocar
# 3 carsinfo
# 4      car
```

Comment: No problem.  A handy-dandy SQL cheat sheet (courtesy of Google) would probably save you some time / headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regular expressions to do this sort of filtering. `grepl` returns a logical vector (TRUE / FALSE) stating whether or not there was a match or not. You can get very sophisticated to match specific items, but a basic query will work in this case:

```
#Using @Joshua's dat data.frame
subset(dat, grepl("car", Keyword, ignore.case = TRUE))

   Keyword
1     cars
2  autocar
3 carsinfo
6      car
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the solution provided by @Chase. Because we do not use subset we do not need a logical vector and can use both `grep` or `grepl`:

```
df <- data.frame(keyword = c("cars", "autocar", "carsinfo", "whatisthat", "donnadrive", "car", "telephone"))
df[grep("car", df$keyword), , drop = FALSE] # or
df[grepl("car", df$keyword), , drop = FALSE]

   keyword
1     cars
2  autocar
3 carsinfo
6      car
```

I took the idea from [Selecting rows where a column has a string like 'hsa..' (partial string match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match)