# Selecting data frame rows based on partial string match in a column

Tags: r, regex, string, match, subset

I want to select rows from a data frame based on partial match of a string in a column, e.g. column 'x' contains the string "hsa". Using `sqldf` - *if* it had a `like` syntax - I would do something like:

`select * from <> where x like 'hsa'`.

Unfortunately, `sqldf` does not support that syntax.

Or similarly:

```
selectedRows <- df[ , df$x %like% "hsa-"]
```

Which of course doesn't work.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your data, preferably using something like `dput(head(conservedData))`.

Answer (score 218):

I notice that you mention a function `%like%` in your current approach. I don't know if that's a reference to the `%like%` from "data.table", but if it is, you can definitely use it as follows.

Note that the object does not have to be a `data.table` (but also remember that subsetting approaches for `data.frame`s and `data.table`s are not identical):

```
library(data.table)
mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %like% "Merc", ]
iris[iris$Species %like% "osa", ]
```

If that is what you had, then perhaps you had just mixed up row and column positions for subsetting data.

---

If you don't want to load a package, you can try using `grep()` to search for the string you're matching. Here's an example with the `mtcars` dataset, where we are matching all rows where the row names includes "Merc":

```
mtcars[grep("Merc", rownames(mtcars)), ]
             mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 240D   24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.0  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230    22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.15 22.9  1  0    4    2
# Merc 280    19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.3  1  0    4    4
# Merc 280C   17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.9  1  0    4    4
# Merc 450SE  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SL  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.6  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3
```

And, another example, using the `iris` dataset searching for the string `osa`:

```
irisSubset <- iris[grep("osa", iris$Species), ]
head(irisSubset)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

For your problem try:

```
selectedRows <- conservedData[grep("hsa-", conservedData$miRNA), ]
```

Comment: +1: also note that `grep` supports regular expressions so you may want to grep for `^hsa-` instead.

Comment: @nico: in fact, `grep` comes from the ed command g/re/p (global / regular expression / print), and it reveals its real power only to the master of regular expression-fu ;-): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Great answer! Is there a way to use %like% to search for two strings that occur together (as in "pet"  and "pip" occuring in a row of a dataframe as "peter piper")?

Answer (score 100):

Try `str_detect()` from the [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) package, which detects the presence or absence of a pattern in a string.

Here is an approach that also incorporates the `%>%` pipe and `filter()` from the [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

CO2 %>%
  filter(str_detect(Treatment, "non"))

   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4
3    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8
4    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2
5    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3
...
```

This filters the sample CO2 data set (that comes with R) for rows where the Treatment variable contains the substring "non".  You can adjust whether `str_detect` finds fixed matches or uses a regex - see the documentation for the stringr package.

Comment: You can also use the **trc_detect** function like this `myDataFrame[str_detect(myDataFrame$key, myKeyPattern),]`

Comment: @Bemipefe don't you mean the *str_detect* function instead of *trc_detect*?

Comment: @Martin Yes you are right. That was a typo.

Answer (score 23):

`LIKE` should work in sqlite:

```
require(sqldf)
df <- data.frame(name = c('bob','robert','peter'),id=c(1,2,3))
sqldf("select * from df where name LIKE '%er%'")
    name id
1 robert  2
2  peter  3
```

Comment: SQLDF is best for listing. However, it cannot delete rows.

Comment: Why is an R package being loaded with `require()` here

Comment: Because it is not standard R library and you have to manually install it and then load using `require` function.

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to simply use `grepl` function:

```
df[grepl('er', df$name), ]
CO2[grepl('non', CO2$Treatment), ]

df <- data.frame(name = c('bob','robert','peter'),
                 id = c(1,2,3)
                 )

# name id
# 2 robert  2
# 3  peter  3
```