# Selecting rows with partial matching where a column has a string not working for decimals

Tags: r, string, data.table, pattern-matching, tidyverse

For example, if I want to keep only those rows of the data `mtcars` where the variable `qsec` contains this decimal `.50`, following the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match), I use:

```
mtcars_stringed<-mtcars%>%filter(str_detect(qsec, ".50"))
mtcars_stringed<-mtcars[mtcars$qsec %like% ".50", ]
mtcars_stringed <- mtcars[grep(".50", mtcars$qsec), ]

View(mtcars_stringed)
```

Surprisingly, all these strategies fail, by returning null, while in fact `mtcars$qsec` has values containing `.50` such as `14.50, 15.50,`

Any alternative solution, or is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you treat a numeric as a string, it is converted `as.character(mtcars$qsec)`. If you look at that,  you'll see that in the conversion, trailing 0s are dropped, so we get, e.g.,  `"14.5", "15.5"`.

It will work if you use the regex pattern `"\\.5$"`, `\\` to make the `.` a `.`, not just "any character", and `$` to match the end of the string.

```
mtcars %>% filter(str_detect(qsec, "\\.5$"))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
# 2 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
```

However, in general, treating decimals as strings can be risky. A better approach might to get rid of the integer with `%% 1` and then test for nearness to `0.5` within some tolerance, this will avoid [precision issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

```
mtcars %>% filter(abs(qsec %% 1 - 0.5) < 1e-10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for:

```
mtcars %>%
 filter(qsec %% 0.50 == 0 & qsec %% 1 != 0)

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
1 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
2 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
```